# findViewById in DialogFragment - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

The dialog I show has two Spinners, and for one of those I'd like to set the selected item (item to select is passed from the main activity with setArguments()/getArguments())

The problem is I can't get the spinner, instead I get a NullPointerException at

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssd_weeksSelectSpinner);`

The DialogFragment code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class DFrag extends DialogFragment 
{
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_schedule_select_dialog, null))
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ssd_select_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {               
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(DFrag.this);                        
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.select_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(DFrag.this);
                DFrag.this.getDialog().cancel();                        
            }
        });

        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

        return builder.create();        
    }


    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       
        View view = getView();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssd_weeksSelectSpinner);
        spinner.setSelection(getArguments().getInt("SelectWeek"));

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public interface DFragListener
    {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    DFragListener mListener;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try 
        {
            mListener = (DFragListener) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " Listener not implemented");
        }
    }
}
```

As requested, layout for the dialog (activity_schedule_select_dialog.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ssd_classLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select_class_label"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"/>
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/ssd_classSelectSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:entries="@array/urnikClasses"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ssd_weekLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select_week_label"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"/>    
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/ssd_weeksSelectSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/weeksArray"/>

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/ssd_DefaultChkbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ssd_DefaultChkBoxTxt"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at com.rogy.scks.urnik.DFrag.onActivityCreated(DFrag.java:91)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-12 13:16:16.288: E/AndroidRuntime(4310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the XML where you defined `ssd_weeksSelectSpinner`

Comment: Edited the original post to include the requested code.

Comment: I assume that's `activity_schedule_select_dialog.xml` file, am I right? And please post the whole stack trace as well.

Comment: Added requested information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution, instead of trying to find the view in `public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

In `public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

I changed from

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_schedule_select_dialog, null))
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ssd_select_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {               
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(DFrag.this);                        
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.select_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(DFrag.this);
                DFrag.this.getDialog().cancel();                        
            }
        });
```

To

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_schedule_select_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ssd_select_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {               
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(DFrag.this);                        
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.select_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(DFrag.this);
                DFrag.this.getDialog().cancel();                        
            }
        });
```

And at the end added

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssd_weeksSelectSpinner);
spinner.setSelection(getArguments().getInt("SelectWeek"));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of extract the Spinner object to a member of the class.

```
public class DFrag extends DialogFragment
{
    private Spinner mSpinner;
    ...
```

Then assign your spinner from the onCreateDialog() function

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_schedule_select_dialog, null);
    // Assign spinner
    mSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssd_weeksSelectSpinner);
    builder.setView(view);
    // Set positive and negative buttons here
    ...
}
```

Now place the value of your spinner on the onCreateView() function

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    mSpinner.setSelection(getArguments().getInt("SelectWeek"));
    ...
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: This present the real trick: inflate to a view variable, so from it, call findViewById. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by this:

> ```
> public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>     {       
>         View view = getView();
>
>         Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssd_weeksSelectSpinner);
>         spinner.setSelection(getArguments().getInt("SelectWeek"));
>
>         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
>     }
> ```

It gives you a NullPointerException, because the spinner, it's not already selected and it's empty, when the activity starts... You need to put this, on a **onItemSelected** listener.

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

See this for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener

EDIT: You also need to import the "R" java file.. I don't see it on the import lists:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
```

EDIT 2: To add a listener to the spinner do this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssd_weeksSelectSpinner);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            // int position is the element you pressed
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, in my first post I wrote that I get NullPointerException at `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.ssd_weeksSelectSpinner);`. I don't see how I would be able to implement the listener, since I still need to get the view with findViewById(), and when I try to get the view with said method I get NullPointerException. I'm trying to set the selected item for the spinner, so that the user instead of seeing the first item in the spinner (and the array the spinner uses), the user would see (for example) the 4th item in the spinner. I imported R java file, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done elegantly using Kotlin:

```
lateinit val myView: View;

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
         .setPositiveButton(R.string.close) { dialog, which -> }
         .setView(LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null, false).apply {
                this@MyDialogFragment.myview = findViewById(R.id.my_view)
         })
         .create()

}


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
  //do something with myView
}
```